# How to handle tap/click event of an item inside a collectionViewcell, Xamarin forms, iOS

Tags: ios, forms, xamarin, xamarin.ios

We are having a xamarin forms app. In home page we have a list of news and clicking on any news it will take us to news details.

Now we want to add a share icon in each row at home page so that tapping on it we can open a pop up dialog.

We are getting issue while handling it existing ios implementation.

We have following implementation:

We are using collectionview and while loading cell for collectionview we are using a customcell which is developed in C#(xamarin forms project)

So the customcell of collectionview is of type, 
ItemCustomcell: Fastgridcell

and it returns a RelativeLayout with one Button and one Label inside it.

Now problem we are facing, how to handle an event of any item which is inside the cell.

For example we have added a button in common template of custom cell, then how we can have the tap event of this button?

Please let me know if I need provide any more details.

Regards,
Koushik Ganguly

Comment: Do you create a custom renderer on Forms? And you want to capture this event on forms or on renderer?

Comment: yes I created a renderer and it would be good if I can handle in renderer,  but any suggestion is welcome. I am stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly define an event in your `Fastgridcell`:

```
public delegate void BtnDidClickDelegate(MyCollectionViewCell cell);
public event BtnDidClickDelegate BtnDidClickEvent;
```

When the button in `Fastgridcell` is clicked fire this event:

```
partial void BtnClick(UIKit.UIButton sender)
{
    BtnDidClickEvent(this);
}
```

Then register this event in your ViewController which places your collectionview:

```
public UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    MyCollectionViewCell cell = collectionView.DequeueReusableCell("Cell", indexPath) as MyCollectionViewCell;

    cell.BtnDidClickEvent += Cell_BtnDidClickEvent;

    return cell;
}
private void Cell_BtnDidClickEvent(MyCollectionViewCell cell)
{
    NSIndexPath selectedIndexPath = MyCollection.IndexPathForCell(cell);
    // In this way, we can get the indexpath which cell's button clicks
}
```

If you want to transfer this parameter to Forms, also use an event or [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am sorry to response late.
My problem is that I can’t handle any one item’s(which is inside collection view cell) tap event. I am trying to elaborate
In xamarin I have the following code

public class ItemCustomCell : FastGridCell {
var customLayout = CreateOwnLayout(); ….
} 

so problem is here I can’t take only btnshareme and add a click even. I have tried to add TapGestureRecognizer 
only for button but still it’s detecting entire row as a single unit.

Please let me know if I am able to convey correctly

Comment: RelativeLayout CreateOwnLayout()   {     var itemLabel = new CustomLabel{      …..
     ….
    };     itemLabel.SetBinding(CustomLabel.TextProperty, new Binding(“title”));      var labelContentView = new ContentView () {      …..
     ….
    };
    var btnshareme = new Button () {      …..
     …..     };
    var btnsharemeContentView = new ContentView () {      …..
     ….
    };        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout ();     layout.Children.Add (labelContentView,x,x,x);                 layout.Children.Add(btnsharemeContentView,x,x,x);                return layout;    }

Comment: I did not have enough place to comment to I divided my dummy code in 2 parts 1. public class ItemCustomCell : FastGridCell { var customLayout = CreateOwnLayout(); …. }   2. RelativeLayout CreateOwnLayout() {....}